# using setTimeout in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, rest, request, settimeout, restful-url

nodeJS is driving me crazy,
i'm trying to resend an API get request until its finished processing, can't get this to work,
help..

```
function checkReturnValue(done){
              request(options, function (error, response) { 
                if (error) throw new Error(error);
                if (response.body.scan_results.progress_percentage != 100) 
                {
                  console.log('if');
                  setTimeout(checkReturnValue(done), 50);
                }
                else 
                {
                  console.log('else');
                  return done(response.body);
                }
              });
          };

  checkReturnValue ((body) => {
   console.log(body);
   });
```

Comment: You're not logging errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **result** of `checkReturnValue(done)` as the function to call after the timeout.

Try supplying a function to be invoked instead:

```
setTimeout(() => checkReturnValue(done), 50);
```